# How do I keep jQuery UI Accordion collapsed by default?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working with jQuery UI Accordion and it works great, but I would like to have the accordion stay closed unless it I click on it.

I am using this code right now, which allows be to toggle it closed:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true });
```

Is there a way to have it closed by default unless it is clicked?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

In addition to the  `collapsible: true` you need to add the `active: false` option ([*documentation*](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active))..

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
```

Comment: Note for other readers: You need "collapsible: true" to make "active: false" work.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to only serve it collapsed for mobile devices?  On desktop computers I want the first tab open. On mobile devices I want all of them closed.

Comment: @user5248 Just check browser in Javascript and make a conditionnal assignment