# accordian menu first slide can't be close default

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using accordion menu

```
 $(function() {
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible:true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
```

it is working fine shown as in example but I want all the menu closed by default and in this code first menu is expanded so what should I do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633971/how-do-i-keep-jquery-ui-accordion-collapsed-by-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with collapsible:true add `active: false`

Answer (score 0):

Please add one more parameter to you current code. Instead this

```
$(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

Kindly use below code...

```
$(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:1,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

active: 1 means zero index you can set any of your accordion index by checking your item index of you accordion.

For Reference [Click Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)