# Collapse - accordion first element opened by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am working with Collapse "Accordion". When my page loads the first collapse is open by default, please suggest the way to make it close by default!!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for help!!

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>
    Click Here for answer:)</h3>
  <div style color: "red;">
    <b>Answer: </b>206 Bones
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery accordion collapsed by default on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575610/jquery-accordion-collapsed-by-default-on-page-load) and [How do I keep jQuery UI Accordion collapsed by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633971)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep jQuery UI Accordion collapsed by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633971/how-do-i-keep-jquery-ui-accordion-collapsed-by-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this property:

```
  active: false
```

Follows a work example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />

</head>
<body>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link href="/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div id="accordion">
<h3>
Click Here for answer:)</h3>
<div style color:"red;">
<b>Answer: </b>206 Bones
  </div></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
 collapsible: true,
       active: false
    });
  } );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the tricks

$("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active: false
    });